# Send email from node.js to Gmail

Tags: node.js, api, email, gmail, send

I have been looking up like 4 different libraries using 2 of them halfway before abandoning to opt for a new one.

I have a node.js api endpoint that should send a mail to my personal gmail account. How could I achieve this, without working around googles OAuth 2 authentication setup. I favor an easy implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) for send emails or you can use services like [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/), here is a tutorial for nodemailer [Tutorial nodemailer](https://codeburst.io/sending-an-email-using-nodemailer-gmail-7cfa0712a799)